# Matlab "loses" the "to the power of" value when importing data for some values

Tags: matlab

I'm importing some very large or small value from a spreadsheet, for some of the imported values, Matlab ignored the "E" sign, and just import the value few decimals place more. For example, `-2.17296171E-36` will be imported as `-2.172961710000000`, which is outright false. Here's the the data:

```
-154.988449E-39
-759.108948E-39
-2.17296171E-36
-4.71616745E-36
-8.67373657E-36
-107.626076E-36
```

Only the first two values and last value are imported correctly:

[image]

I'm guessing this has to do with precision, any idea how to properly imports this kind of data?

Comment: can you post the code, how you import the data?

Comment: While importing just check that are you using option `numbers`

Comment: I am importing with option numbers and it is working fine

Comment: We need some more details here to reproduce this. What format is the "spreadsheet" you're reading? .xls? .csv? What command in MATLAB are you using to import the data?